# SImple MySQL update not working with generic error

Tags: mysql

I have never had this happened to me before, it is very very strange,

very simple SQL update is not working:

```
UPDATE table givi_user_sessions set givi_user_clientid='somevalue' where givi_user_id=2;
```

i tried other variations like:

```
UPDATE table givi_user_sessions set  where givi_user_id=3 where givi_user_id=2
```

and this too:

```
UPDATE table `givi_user_sessions` set  where `givi_user_id`=3 where `givi_user_id`=2
```

All those options gave me following error:

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table givi_user_sessions set givi_user_clientid='somevalue' where givi_user_id=2' at line 1

I double checked that table exists, and also that column names are correct,
the only thing that I can recall is that i changed table name from user_sessions to givi_user_sessions, but that should not matter at all, unless something got messed in mysql engine, because I definately think that my sql is correct. or maybe i have been working for too long today.

any advices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include the keyword "table" in your query.  You can check the syntax of the update query here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

It should look like this:

```
UPDATE givi_user_sessions set givi_user_clientid='somevalue' where givi_user_id=2;
```

Comment: ooh, unbeleivable, i was looking at the code for several hours, and did not notice that, thanks.